# highstock stockchart flag is not getting stored in series data && on click popup is not coming && 2 flags rendered

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

In high charts, if I add flags,annotations for the first time they are added to series and on click popup for deletion, cancellation is showing, however after updating i am calling setannotations function based on savedchartoptions then annotations are getting stored and flags are not stored,so on updatechartdata functions again i am pushing fags into series then it restored after updating chart data but the flag popup is not showing. While clicking on flags I get an error **cannot read property 'popup' of undefined**.

Issue2:-The flags are generated twice one over other, while removing too we need to remove both of them. Any insights on this will be really helpful.

```
  savedChartOptions = {
          chart: {
            height: $(window).height() - ($(".modal-dialog").outerHeight(true) - $(".modal-dialog").innerHeight()) - $(".modal-header").outerHeight(),
            width: $('.modal-header').outerWidth(true),
          },
          navigation: {
            bindings: {
              measure: {
                annotationsOptions: {
                  typeOptions: {
                    background: {
                      fill: 'rgba(207, 219, 253, 0.5)'
                    },
                    label: {
                      style: {
                          color: 'Gray40'
                      }
                  }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              dataGrouping: {
                forced: true
              },
              lineWidth: 1
            }
          },
          yAxis: [{
              gridLineWidth: 0.4,
              gridLineColor: '#4d4d4d',
              labels: {
                align: 'left',
                format: '{value:.2f}'
              },
              height: '80%',
              resize: {
                enabled: true
              }
            },
            {
              gridLineWidth: 0.4,
              reversed:false,
              labels: {
                align: 'left',
                format: '{value:.2f}'
              },
              top: '80%',
              height: '20%',
              tickAmount :3,
              tickPixelInterval:10,
              offset: 0
            }
          ],
          tooltip: {
            shape: 'square',
            headerShape: 'callout',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            enabled: true,
            split: true,
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            valueDecimals: 2,
            // valueSuffix: ' mm',
            formatter: formatToolTip,
            positioner: function(width, height, point) {
              var chart = this.chart,
                position;
              if (point.isHeader) {
                position = {
                  x: Math.max(
                    // Left side limit
                    chart.plotLeft,
                    Math.min(
                      point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - width / 2,
                      // Right side limit
                      chart.chartWidth - width - chart.marginRight
                    )
                  ),
                  y: point.plotY
                };
              } else {
                position = {
                  x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
                  y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop
                };
              }
              return position;
            }
          },
          series: [{
              type: scope.chartSeriesType || 'line',
              id: 'primary-chart-series',
              name: scope.metaData.primaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
              data: scope.primaryApplicationChartData,
              dataGrouping:{
                approximation: timeIntervalType,
                forced: true,
                units: [
                  [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              type: 'line',
              id: 'secondary-chart-series',
              name: scope.metaData.secondaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
              data: scope.secondaryApplicationChartData,
              dataGrouping:{
                approximation: timeIntervalType,
                forced: true,
                units: [
                  [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                ]
              },
              yAxis: 1
            },
            {
              type: scope.chartSeriesType || 'line',
              id: 'compare-primary-chart-series',
              name: 'Compare '+scope.metaData.primaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
              data: scope.primaryCompareApplicationChartData,
              dataGrouping:{
                approximation: timeIntervalType,
                forced: true,
                units: [
                  [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                ]
              }
            }
          ],

 // saves chart annotations and flags to be later restored
      function setChartAnnotations() {
        var navigation = stockChart.navigationBindings,
          navChart = navigation.chart,
          indicators = [],
          flags = [];
        options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedChartOptions));//pushing flags into series if type is flags.
        navChart.series.forEach(function(series) {
          if (series.type === 'flags') {
            options.series.push(series.userOptions);
          }
        });
        navChart.yAxis.forEach(function(yAxis) {
          if (navigation.utils.isNotNavigatorYAxis(yAxis)) {
            options.yAxis.push(yAxis.options);
          }
        });
        navChart.annotations.forEach(function(annotation, index) { //if there is no annotations in options making annotations array empty.
          if (!options.annotations) {
            options.annotations = [];
          }
          options.annotations.push(annotation.userOptions);//pushing annotations into annotations array
        });
        options.navigation.bindings.measure.annotationsOptions.typeOptions.background.fill = 'rgba(207, 219, 253, 0.5)';
      }

function updateChartData() {
       var series_array = [];
       angular.forEach(options.series , function(seriestypeobj){
       if(seriestypeobj.type== "flags")
       {
           series_array.push(seriestypeobj);
       }
       });
       options.series = [{
             type: scope.chartSeriesType || 'line',
             id: 'aapl-ohlc',
             name: scope.metaData.primaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
             data: scope.primaryApplicationChartData,
             dataGrouping:{
                  approximation: timeIntervalType,
                  forced: true,
                  units: [
                      [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                      ]
              }
          },
          {
             type: 'line',
             id: 'aapl-volume',
             name: scope.metaData.secondaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
             data: scope.secondaryApplicationChartData,
             dataGrouping:{
                 approximation: timeIntervalType,
                 forced: true,
                 units: [
                    [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                 ]
             },
              yAxis: 1
          },
          {
             type: scope.chartSeriesType || 'line',
             id: 'compare-primary-chart-series',
             name: 'Compare ' + scope.metaData.primaryApplicationChartName || 'Data',
             data: scope.primaryCompareApplicationChartData,
             dataGrouping:{
                 approximation: timeIntervalType,
                 forced: true,
                 units: [
                    [scope.timeInterval.timeUnit || 'day', [scope.timeInterval.timeDelta || 1]]
                 ]
              }
           }
         ];

         options.annotations = options.annotations.concat(series_array);
                 }
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aohx.png)

Comment: You should probably include some of the relevant code segments that produce this behavior.

Comment: I added some information and relevant code this may help you to understand.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/543l0p0qq4